# Cross Validation for Different Metrics - Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When I am doing cross validation using Python's Sklearn and take the score of different metrics (accuracy, precision, etc.) like this:

```
result_accuracy = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=10)
result_precision = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='precision', cv=10)
result_recall = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='recall', cv=10)
result_f1 = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='f1', cv=10)
```

Did every execution of `cross_val_score()` function for different metrics made the same 10 folds of the training data or not? If not, do I need to make the general 10-folds first using KFold, like this:

```
seed = 7
kf = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)

result_accuracy = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=kf)
result_precision = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='precision', cv=kf)
result_recall = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='recall', cv=kf)
result_f1 = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='f1', cv=kf)
```

Answer (score 2):

It only really matters if you want to shuffle your data in the cross-validation. The default for both `cross_val_score` and `KFold` is to NOT shuffle.

If you do want to shuffle your second option is best if you want to make sure that you are comparing scores across the same splits on the data.

Keep in mind that in the default `KFold(shuffle=False)`, so if you want to shuffle your data make sure that you set Kfold to:

`kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)`